# Ruby class-level instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was doing a refresher on Ruby and I saw this guy's blog about creating class-level instance variable in Ruby. I am still trying to understand what the code actually does here. His blog can be found here

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

and I have created a simple code based on his example to show what I am trying to understand

```
class Polygon
  class << self; attr_accessor :sides end
  @sides = 10
  def initialize
  end
end

class Triangle < Polygon
  @sides = 3
  class << self; attr_accessor :sides end
  def initialize
  end
end

puts Triangle.sides #3
puts Polygon.sides #10
```

So the line that I really want to understand is (probably you guys have guessed it),

```
class << self; attr_accessor :sides end
```

What does this really do? what is he appending self to class ? is class an array then? Please elaborate as much as you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<<` is not a method (that is not exclusive to Array BTW), but is the syntax for defining a [metaclass](http://vision-media.ca/resources/ruby/understanding-ruby-metaclasses)

Basically, a metaclass is THE class of a single object (some people calls them singleton classes). For example, if you define

```
x = Foo.new
y = Foo.new
class << x
  def quack
    "Quack!"
  end
end
```

then calling `x.quack` will return "Quack", but `y.quack` will throw a `NoMethodError`. So, the code is only evaluated on x's metaclass.

But... classes are objects too, right? So, when you evaluate that line, it is the equivalent of doing

```
class << Triangle
  attr_accessor :sites
end
```

which will just define an instance variable **in the metaclass of Triangle**. This is, the `Triange` class, which is an object too, will have an instance variable called `sides`

More info in [this](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) and [this](http://yinkei.com/the-ruby-metaclass) links. Once you get the idea, go to the nearest irb console and experiment with that.